How to handle with different Python/pip versions in my computer?
I've been using ArcGIS 10.8 in my computer, that works on Python 2.7.
Since I've started learning Python (v3.12), I've been facing some problems, especially with pip versions
Once Python 2.7 is installed in my computer due to ArcGIS, running pip on CMD is never up to date
At the same time, however i try to update pip, it shows:
C:\Users\Gabriel>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\gabriel\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (24.0)

I can't uninstall or upgrade ArcGIS, but also have to use latest pip version so I can install the packages
Is there any way I can manage using two differents pip versions working, or something?
Thanks

You're describing virtual environments! Each virtual environment that you create can contain separate versions of packages, or even different versions of Python. You can find lots of resources online describing virtualenvs, how they work, and how to set them up.

been using ArcGIS 10.8 in my computer, that works on Python 2.7 Does it really only work with Python 2.7?  That version is VERY old...

To manage your Python projects cleanly, consider using virtualenv
Virtualenv is a powerful tool that enables you to create isolated Python environments, allowing you to work on different projects with different dependencies without conflicts.
How to get started:

Install virtualenv: Begin by installing the virtualenv package using pip:
pip install virtualenv


Create a new environment: Once installed, you can create a new virtual environment for your project:
virtualenv venv


Activate the environment: Activate the virtual environment to start using it for your project:
venv\Scripts\activate



With your virtual environment set up, you're ready to work on your Python project in an isolated space. Install specific packages and versions without affecting your system-wide Python environment.
